# In the question given below

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

in the question if we go in accordance with+M effect instead of+I effect we will get the required answer but why are we going in accordance with +M effect and when do and how do we choose which phenomenon to consider ?

Comment: +M has priority over I effect

Comment: Please try to find a reasonable title for your question. While being as concise as possible, it shall indicate, without ambiguity, the subject matter of the question in such a way as to distinguish it from that of other questions, without going into unnecessary detail.

Comment: Instead of a blanket statement like "resonance is more important than inductive effects", I'd offer this version: generally, resonance effects are observed to be more effective at stabilising carbocations than inductive effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CH3 does not show resonance effects noticeably.

In case of solving problems like this, the order to consider is *+M >+H >+I*,
where +M refers to the resonance effect, +H to the hyper conjugation effect and +I to the inductive effect.

Note that in the above problem, if you consider the number of *alpha-hydrogen* atoms involved in hyper conjugation, you will get the correct order.

Answer (score -2):

+M or +R dominate over inductive. That's because+M involves π electrons which are more reactive than the sigma electrons. + I operates through sigma electrons. So therefore+M effect has priority over +I.

Comment: Will the statement always hold true , means we must first check for +M effect before+I

Comment: Yes. +M must be checked before +I. The order to be followed is M > H > I.